# tying together the 'xxd' command with output

Tags: vim, xxd

I have the following hex dump:

```
00000000: 2345 5854 5241 530a 0a31 2e20 746f 2061  #EXTRAS..1. to a
00000010: 6464 2075 7365 723a 2060 7375 646f 2075  dd user: `sudo u
00000020: 7365 7261 6464 205b 7573 6572 6e61 6d65  seradd [username
00000030: 5d60 2061 6e64 2074 6865 6e20 6073 7564  ]` and then `sud
00000040: 6f20 7061 7373 7764 205b 7573 6572 6e61  o passwd [userna
00000050: 6d65 5d60 2074 6f20 6164 6420 7061 7373  me]` to add pass
00000060: 776f 7264 0a0a 312e 2074 6865 2063 6f6d  word..1. the com
00000070: 6d61 6e64 2061 626f 7665 2077 696c 6c20  mand above will 
00000080: 6e6f 7420 6164 6420 6120 686f 6d65 2064  not add a home d
00000090: 6972 6563 746f 7279 2066 6f72 2074 6865  irectory for the
000000a0: 2061 6464 6564 2075 7365 720a 0a31 2e20   added user..1. 
000000b0: 746f 2067 6976 6520 7468 6520 7573 6572  to give the user
000000c0: 2061 2068 6f6d 6520 6469 7265 6374 6f72   a home director
000000d0: 792c 2069 6e63 6c75 6465 2074 6865 2060  y, include the `
000000e0: 2d6d 6020 666c 6167 0a0a 0a              -m` flag...
```

vim is telling me its 235b and simple command I wrote to count all characters is telling me there are 243 characters:

```
xxd -ps extras.md | sed 's/\(..\)/\1\n/g' | wc -l
```

in addition, the left memory column is telling its taking up: 'd0 + 11 bytes so 219 bytes'? If I'm understanding that right.

can someone tie 219, 235 and 243 together for me? or tell me i did everything wrong

that works too but let me know how to fix please

Comment: The left column of the last line is not 000000d0 but 000000e0. So 0xe0 + 11 bytes = 235 bytes. The rest somehow smells like a possible homework exercise, so here's a hint: look at `xxd -ps extras.md | head -1` and compare it to `xxd -ps extras.md | head -1 | cat -A`. It should show you something that is throwing your command's calculation off. Also, check `wc --help`: you are overcomplicating things.

Comment: less of a homework assignment, more personal interest. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex dump displays characters from 0x00 (0) to 0xEA (234). This makes 235 characters in total.

Your command `xxd -ps extras.md | sed 's/\(..\)/\1\n/g'` also outputs 8 additional empty lines (the end of lines of the original `xxd` output) which are counted by `wc -l`.

Solution: only count the lines that are non empty

```
xxd -ps extras.md | sed 's/\(..\)/\1\n/g' | grep -c .
```

Comment: Ah okay understood. Can you explain what 'grep -c' does? does it count only the lines that aren't blank? so in other words, match any non-empty pattern?

Comment: @Mathew `grep` selects lines from its input that match a pattern. The pattern here is `.` (any character). The `-c` option asks `grep` to display the total amount of selected lines, instead of the lines themselves.